# entity framework Загрузка связанных данных

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

у меня есть две таблицы(phone, purchase) которые связаны между собой и я хочу что бы в Information.cshtml выводилось связанные данные,я пробовал ,но не получается, помогите если можете

Models:

```
public class Phone 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Purchase> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Purchase 
{
    public int PurchaseId { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int PhoneId { get; set; }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IPhoneRepository
{
    IEnumerable <Phone> GetAllPhones();
    IEnumerable <Purchase> GetAllInformation();
    Phone GetPhoneId(int phoneId); 
}
```

Repository

```
 private readonly IPhoneRepository _phoneRepository;
 Db Db = new Db();

public IEnumerable<Purchase> GetAllInformation()
 { 
   return Db.Purchases.Include(p => p.PhoneId);
 }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Information()
{
    var purchase = _phoneRepository.GetAllInformation();

    var homeViewModel= new HomeViewModels()
    {
         Purchases = purchase.ToList()
    };
    return View(homeViewModel);
 }
```

HomeViewModels:

```
public class HomeViewModels
{
    public List <Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public List <Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
}
```

Information.cshtml

```
@model Shop.Views.ViewModels.HomeViewModels

@{
    foreach(var information in Model.Purchases) 
    {
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Information">@information.Country</a>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Information">@information.City</a>
        <br />
    }
    foreach(var phone in Model.Phones)
    {
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Information">@phone.Price</a>
    }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас саязь 1-M, то у вас в классе `Purchase` помимо `PhoneId` должно быть поле типа `Phone`

Comment: @tym32167 добавил тип Phone, а что дальше?

Comment: [Отношение один ко многим](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.5.php)